# Oracle Enterprise Manager rounding tablespace size?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, tablespace, oracle-enterprise-manager

**Does Oracle Enterprise Manager round values or am I missing something in my SQL query?**

OEM is showing the tablespace size for SYSAUX as 2GB. But, when I query the dba_data_files table, I get 1940 MB. You can see the query I'm using in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this topic: [Binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

You have 2,034,237,440 Bytes.

When you do `2,034,237,440 / 1024 /1024` then you get 1,940 **Mi**Bytes (not **M**Bytes!)

2,034,237,440 Bytes is equal to 2.034237440 **G**Bytes, I assume this is just rounded to 2 GB.

However, Oracle Enterprise Manager may does the same error as so many other people, see section [Inconsistent use of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Inconsistent_use_of_units)

Comment: That's interesting. For SYSAUX, it looks like it's using the decimal prefix. But for the others, OEM is definitely using the binary prefix. Any idea why OEM would differ its calculations between the different tablespaces?